# How to find all Preview services in my Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I have a few resource groups in my Azure subscription. Is there an Azure CLI Powershell script / command ----  to find all/any services that are being used which are in [Preview] and are not [Generally Available].

Comment: Have you already looked at the Azure modules to see if the out of box cmdlets to get you over your use case? Download, them and look at the examples. What have you already tried. Show your code.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services) is helpful.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to do that via powershell or cli.

If you want to know if a service is in preview or generally available, check out https://azure-overview.com/.